# Как зашифровать сообщение в aes256 на чистом JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, aes

Охота зашифровать сообщение в AES256. Допустим есть ключ и есть сообщение. Причем охота сделать это средствами JS (не NodeJS, не PHP, не что то еще. для остального решения есть)

Вопрос: как такое реализовать?

p.s. гуглил. То ли у меня гугль ищет решения только на NodeJS толи я не умею искать.

p.p.s. еслиу кого ссылка с примером - прошу, поделитесь

Comment: Гуглить "pure JavaScript AES". Первая же ссылка https://github.com/ricmoo/aes-js/

Comment: а в чем проблема с использованием JS? Неясен алгоритм или что?

Comment: >  гугль ищет решения только на NodeJS  <

Слово "NodeJS" будет встречаться в большинстве случаев, т.к его наличие - обязательное условие для npm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Взято с [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Victornpb/wxs1bbxg/)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    // encrypt listener
    $('#encryptBtn').click(function () {
        var t = new Date();
        var ciphertext = Aes.Ctr.encrypt($('#plaintext').val(), $('#password').val(), 256);
        $('#encrypt-time').html(((new Date() - t)) + 'ms');
        $('#cipher').val(ciphertext);
    });

    // decrypt listener
    $('#decryptBtn').click(function () {
        var t = new Date();
        var plain = Aes.Ctr.decrypt($('#cipher').val(), $('#password').val(), 256);
        $('#decrypt-time').html(((new Date() - t)) + 'ms');
        $('#plaintext').val(plain);
    });


    $('#plaintextDiv .clear').click(function () {
        $('#plaintext').val("");
    });
    $('#cipherDiv .clear').click(function () {
        $('#cipher').val("");
    });


});
```

```css
.panel button.pull-right {
    margin-right: 1em;
}
.panel button.pull-left {
    margin-left: 1em;
}
textarea{
    font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/victornpb/f639f37373be0f6e82e1/raw/5d8f7ee8b32ae04de087d2377d8086e3389ee411/AES.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<div class="container">
     <h1>AES-256</h1> 
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input id="password" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="1234" value="1234">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="plaintextDiv" class="col-md-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="row">
                 <h3 class="panel-title text-center">Plain text</h3>

            </div>
            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                    <button class="clear btn btn-default">Clear</button>
                    <button class="copy btn btn-default">Copy</button>
                    <button class="paste btn btn-default">Paste</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <textarea id="plaintext" class="form-control" rows="10">Hello World!</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="cipherDiv" class="col-md-1 text-center">
    <div class="row">
        <button id="encryptBtn" class="btn btn-primary ">Encrypt <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <button id="decryptBtn" class="btn btn-primary "><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-left"></i> Decrypt</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="cipherDiv" class="col-md-5">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="row">
                 <h3 class="panel-title text-center">Cipher</h3>

            </div>
            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                    <button class="clear btn btn-default">Clear</button>
                    <button class="copy btn btn-default">Copy</button>
                    <button class="paste btn btn-default">Paste</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <textarea id="cipher" class="form-control" rows="10"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: оно! никаких npm пакетов )